# Find the minimum of data filtered by another column

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a sequence of couples as follows:

```
            A            B
1          Date        Value
2       01/10/2014       3
3       05/03/2015       7
4       10/12/2015       9
5       15/01/2016       11
```

Now I want to get the minimum value of the `B` column only for current year (hence, `7`).

I know I can insert a `C` column with values equal (for each row) to:

```
=if(and(A2>=date(year(now());1;1);A2<=date(year(now());12;31);B2;"")
```

hence retrieving `min(C2:C5)`.

But, since I don't want to use an additional column (I don't want `C`), how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To get the minimum of filtered data, apply `min` to [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).

```
=min(filter(B2:B, year(A2:A)=year(today())))
```

It seems more natural to use `today` instead of `now` here, since you don't need the time component.